STM32H755 + Lwip. Why do I receive UDP broadcast packet on a TCP connection?
I have a board connected with a server on my company network.
The server sends a file (150kb) to my board via TCP. The IP address of my board is given by a DHCP server.
I use the socket API from Lwip to manage the TCP connection on my board. The connection is good, the data transfer seems to be good.
With Wireshark I see that the server sends data to my IP address, and some other devices on the network sends frames to destination 192.168.1.255 or 255.255.255.255 with UDP protocol.
Sometimes, during the file transfer the lwip_recv() function returns data coming from these frames.
In the low_level_init(), function from ethernetif.c, the broadcast is not activated.
The connection code is called when the IP address is given by DHCP server:
        mSocketID = lwip_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        //init addr
        memset(&waddr, 0, sizeof(waddr));
            //init the structure
        waddr.sin_len = sizeof(waddr);
        waddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        waddr.sin_port = PP_HTONS(SOCK_TARGET_PORT);
        waddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SOCK_TARGET_HOST);
        if(lwip_connect(mSocketID, (struct sockaddr*)&waddr, sizeof(waddr))==0)
        {
            CIT_ServerConnected();

            /* Server connected */
                mServerConnected = true;
        }


The reception code is called every ms :

static uint8_t mBufferRXEthernet[1500];

                wNbBytesReceived = lwip_recv(mSocketID, mBufferRXEthernet, 1024, MSG_DONTWAIT);
        if(wNbBytesReceived > 0)
        {
            CIT_Reception(mBufferRXEthernet, wNbBytesReceived);
                }


In ethernetif.c a part of the code is:
/* Accept ARP traffic */
netif->flags = NETIF_FLAG_ETHARP;
If I slow down the server with 300ms between two data frames it works fine. The received data are always the data sent by the server.
I also tried in fixed IP and disabled broadcast at MAC level. At real ethernet speed it works fine too.
